# MS SQL Serv: Why is my query running so slow?

Tags: sql-server

Self-taught, small business DIYer here. Running MS Sql Server '14.

I have ran this query now 4 times a month for almost 2 years. However the last two months the query run time has become unbearably long. What use to run in 2-3 minutes now takes 24+ hours.

I import weekly files into a monthly table and then dedupe that table against the previous 2 months tables to get a unique file for export. The volume of the tables has stayed consistent as is the data type, the index and the allowable nulls.

It is not computing power. I can substitute last January's file in for this January's and the query runs in minutes. Again, this started with December 2016's file. Any previous file runs very quickly.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Query:

```
SELECT [2017_JAN].*
 FROM [dbo].[2017_JAN]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[2016_NOV]
   ON [2016_NOV].[ID] = [2017_JAN].[ID]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[2016_DEC]
   ON [2016_DEC].[ID] = [2017_JAN].[ID]
WHERE   [2016_NOV].[ID]  IS NULL
    and [2016_DEC].[ID]  IS NULL
```

Comment: It seems that all tables has the same schema, why are you using a table for every year_month?

Comment: what about table sizes... log files size... index may have to be rebuilt?... you have to do a checklist on all that

Comment: you can run a dbcc checktable to see if table has any broken data

Comment: I have customer's that prefer no dupes in a month, some who prefer no dupes across 90 days and some who don't care at all about dupes. Once we leave a month the data is rather useless other than for suppression.

Comment: @NicoRiff Rebuilding the index on the DEC_2016 file fixed it Nico. That was probably the first place you would have looked huh? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: glad it helped you!

Comment: I will put it as answer just to give a closure to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said, rebuilding indexes on your involved tables solved the problem.
In this cases, you can run a DBCC CHECKTABLE  to ensure your tables health also.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes won't work if you do a select *. If you just select the actual columns you want, it'd avoid the table scans and run faster.

Another tip, if you do have enough memory, you could add a hash query hint to your joins:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT [2017_JAN].*
 FROM [dbo].[2017_JAN]
  LEFT HASH JOIN [dbo].[2016_NOV]
   ON [2016_NOV].[ID] = [2017_JAN].[ID]
  LEFT HASH JOIN [dbo].[2016_DEC]
   ON [2016_DEC].[ID] = [2017_JAN].[ID]
WHERE   [2016_NOV].[ID]  IS NULL
    and [2016_DEC].[ID]  IS NULL
```

Overall, we'd have to look at your tables, keys, and indexes to optimize it all.

Good luck!